# Different Fajr prayer time which one to follow?

Tags: salat

OK so I just download an app and for prayer time it is showing a large amount of prayer calculation hubs like:-

**Muslim World League** - 04:52 AM
**ISNA** - 5:06 AM
**Musulamns de France** - 05:19 AM

So which one I can follow anyone I find suitable or ?? And if I can not follow anyone than what is the role of others Hub ?

> I need to fast that why I am focussing more on fajr prayer time

Comment: I think what you look for is answered here [Figuring out the right calculation method of prayer time](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/figuring-out-right-calculation-method-of-prayer-time) in your case it would be best to use a method from a country which is close to you, the closest the more exact, you may also rely on the calculations of moonsighting.com. ISNA is better for northern America, World League Europe etc. (See also [Prayer times calculation organisations differences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/prayer-times-calculation-organisations-differences)

Comment: As-salam-alaikum Bismillah , can't I follow timing of musulamns-de-France as it suits me best. Is anything wrong with it , as I am secretly following islam so it is hard for me to manage time and especially if it is too early as I live with my parents , sleep with my parents so is there anything wrong in following whichever I like!

Comment: Yes it might not be accurate, so you might falsely be eating at a time you should be fasting or praying before the time and that's a sin or might be considered as such, now as you have been informed!

Comment: Bismillah I am in India which one I need to follow ? I do not know the time table of people in India which they follow as I am living in area of India where there are majority of Hindus live , even there is not a single mosque in my city , I have not greeted a single Muslim in my city , so what to do which one to follow  can you please directly tell me , I am so confused and also please keep in mind if it is allowed for me to follow any timetable I like and if it is not than tell me which one I need to follow in India thanks in advance for your help Bismillah.

Comment: The answer below says: University of Islamic Sciences, Karachi (18 degrees both): Pakistan, Bangladesh, India, Afghanistan, parts of Europe and I added the information that you may get a more or less exact calculation from moonsighting.com

Comment: Is it not allowed or makrooh if I follow ISNA or Muslim and de France time table in Asia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75561/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-anonykous).

Answer (score 2):

Follow the hub (actual term is calculation method) that the people around you in your area follow. Only difference in prayer time for the madhhabs is ‘Asr (Hanafi v. Hanbali, Shafi’i, Maliki). Here are the hubs:

> Muslim World Leauge (18 degrees Fajr, 17 degrees Isha’): Europe, far east, parts of the US
>
> Egyptian General Authority of Survey (19.5 degrees Fajr, 17.5 Isha’): Africa, Syria, Iraq, Lebanon, Malaysia, parts of the US
>
> Islamic Society of North America (15 degrees both): Parts of the US, Canada, parts of the UK
>
> University of Islamic Sciences, Karachi (18 degrees both): Pakistan, Bangladesh, India, Afghanistan, parts of Europe
>
> Umm Al-Qura (19 degrees Fajr, 90 minutes after sunset Isha’): The Arabian Peninsula

Moreover, Imam Abu Hanifa’s view was that it should be 18 degrees both, but his disciples’ view was 18 degrees Fajr and 15 degrees Isha’ like the rest of the madhhabs (Shafi’i, Maliki, Hanbali). I suggest [IslamicFinder](https://www.islamicfinder.org) which allows you to choose the Karachi hub (Abu Hanifa’s way) or the others’ way by customizing the degrees in the settings.

So, University of Islamic Sciencies, Karachi, if you are using Abu Hanifa’s view or customize the settings if you are a non-Hanafi (Abu Hanifa strict) person. You can also ask your mosque which calculation method they use, then use their timings or just use their hub. [1](https://www.islamicfinder.org)

EDIT: I decided to add also Jafari people do 16 degrees on both, Fajr and Isha’.

Comment: I am living in Non-Muslim area so can I follow anyone for fasting

Comment: Use University of Islamic Sciences, Karachi if you are India, sir, it is not that hard, if you do Jihad in waking up earlier while you are struggling to do so, that is very good, there shall be a reward for you because of this.

Comment: Thanks brother may Allah forgive you and give you jannah

Comment: Insha’allah, all of the brothers and sisters in the Ummah.

Answer (score 1):

Fajr prayer is to be done during the pre-dawn period until the first ray of light. There’s no need to obsess over which specific minute and second. Just make sure to pray before the official sun rise of your location.

Evidences are many, here’s some from Muwatta: (note: Fajr = Subh ; there is the Fajr prayer which is a naafil and different then the obligatory Subh, but that’s a different topic)

> Hadith No: 5
>   Narrated/Authority of
>   Yahya related to me from Malik from Zayd ibn Aslam from Ata ibn Yasar and from Busr ibn Said and from al-Araj-all of whom related it from Abu Hurayra - that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "**Whoever manages to do a raka of subh before the sun has risen has done subh in time**, and whoever manages to do a raka of asr before the sun has set has done asr in time."
>
> Hadith No: 3
>   Narrated/Authority of
>   Yahya related to me from Malik from Zayd ibn Aslam that Ata ibn Yasar said, "A man came to the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, and asked him about the time of the subh prayer. The Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, did not answer him, but in the morning he prayed subh at first light. The following morning he prayed subh when it was much lighter, and then said, 'Where is the man who was asking about the time of the prayer?' The man replied, 'Here I am, Messenger of Allah.' He said,'**The time is between these two.'**
>
> Hadith No: 4
>   Narrated/Authority of
>   Yahya related to me from Malik from Yahya ibn Said from Amra bint Abd ar-Rahman that A'isha, the wife of the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "The Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, used to pray subh and the women would leave wrapped in their garments and they could not yet be recognised in the darkness."

Comment: He wanted to know when he should start his fasting and which calculation to use, not when to pray Fajr. As I agree with you, there isn’t that big importance on which second you pray one, he is asking when to start his fast.