# How do Isha/Fajr times work in the summer?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

new revert here. I've been trying to wrap my head around prayer times and I've looked through salah times throughout the year in my location.

For example, on one day in late June, when days are the longest, my app tells me the Isha time is 00:56 a.m., and the next day's Fajr is also 00:56 a.m. That would be the exact same time. How does that work? Am I supposed to do Isha and the next day's Fajr back-to-back? Should I combine them?

Can someone explain like I'm five?

I'm using the Muslim World League method of calculation, in case that matters.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please be aware that each calculation method is locally applicable: there's no overall algorithm that I know of, because parameters must be adapted for the southern and northern hemisphere. For further information please refer to [Prayer times calculation organisations differences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/prayer-times-calculation-organisations-differences) and [Figuring out right calculation method of prayer time](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/figuring-out-right-calculation-method-of-prayer-time).

Comment: I would try some other apps\websites to make sure its not a bug. Prayer times vary with the location and some areas close to the poles will not experience all the required times. In this case there are a couple of opinions, islamqa discusses one of them: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/135415/